# Nextjs page refresh after clicking a route button for the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

Basically, when the initial page build happens and we are on the index page, after clicking any button that changes the route, for example, the Link tag, the router method using push and replace, (yes, i have tried both) triggers a page refresh the first time, after the reload happens and i click the button again, rendering actually happens and i get to the route i want, how do i make it so that the first refresh does not happen and the user can just get to the route they want? Please ask me any more information you need.

Comment: Show us some code please?

Comment: The issue is fixed, it was about the dev build, but thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about next.js but I think it doesn't refresh the page in production. Even if it does then next.js will caches that on the server which means only 1st user has to face the refresh.

Comment: Oh hold on a sec', let me try it with the prod build, thank you for the advice up front!

Comment: That is absolutely true, it didn't do the same thing in the prod build, thank you for the great advice!

Comment: If you find it helpful and it correctly addresses the problem then can you mark this as the answer.